# Adding labels on force diagram d3 js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to add labels to a force graph that is created dynamically. Here is the code.

This is the relevant part of the code where I add the text elements.

```
labels = labels.data(links);

labels.exit().remove();

labels.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("dy", 16)
    .append("textPath")
    .attr("startOffset", "50%")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d,i){ return "#id" + i})
    .text("label");
```

Here is a fiddle I created that demonstrates the problem. - https://jsfiddle.net/soorajchn/u49s9sth/

(Since its large `stackoverflow` does not allow me to create the code snippet of that size )

If i click the add button a node will be created and a connecting line can be drawn by dragging from one node to another. To move around a node use ctrl + drag.

I'm trying to add the label and the text element is getting added. But it always takes up 0 height and width and ends up at top left corner of the screen. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Where do you want labels to be?

Comment: Why the title `Disable an element in select2 on change not working`?

Comment: I have no idea how that crept in. Might be the title from last unasked question. Edited anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to set the ID to the path elements. Try this way.

```
 path.enter().append('svg:path')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .attr("id",function(d, i) {
      return "id" + i; //Sets id to the path elements which will be used in textPaths later
    })
    .classed('selected', function(d) {
      return d === selected_link;
    })
    .style('marker-start', function(d) {
      return d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : '';
    })
    .style('marker-end', function(d) {
      return d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : '';
    })
    .on('mousedown', function(d) {
      if (d3.event.ctrlKey) return;

      // select link
      mousedown_link = d;
      if (mousedown_link === selected_link) selected_link = null;
      else selected_link = mousedown_link;
      selected_node = null;
      restart();
    });
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u49s9sth/1/)